# Sitecore PowerShell fast Search in Script

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I used Sitecore PowerShell Extensions module to create script, that copy the relation from one item to the related item.

I use `Get-ChildItem` to get all the items which will have relation on specific fields

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse . | Where-Object {
    $_.TemplateName -match $'myTemplate' -and
    $_.Fields[$fromfield].Value -ne $null -and
    $_.Fields[$fromfield].Value -ne ""
} | ForEach-Object {
}
```

I took about 1 min to fetch all the items because the data is big.

So I tried to use `Find-Item` to make the search process faster

```
Find-Item -Index 'sitecore_mastre_index' -Where 'TemplateName = @0' -WhereValues 'myTemplate'
```

It gave me below warning, note that I use  Sitecore Version 7.2

> WARNING: The parameter Where is not supported on this version of Sitecore due to platform limitations.
>
> This parameter is supported starting from Sitecore Version 7.5

Is there a way to retrieve the data using PowerShell in way faster than using `Get-ChildItem`?

Note: if I use  `Get-Item .` the query returns only the first 100 items. I have many more items.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing more about your variables.  Have you tried the exclude/include/filter parameters of Get-Childitem?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things to consider.

**Example:** Get-ChildItem

```
# Essentially touches all of the items in the database. 
# It's one of the most common ways to query the items, 
# but should be a narrow path.

Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\" -Recurse
```

**Example:** Find-Item

```
# This example is what you need to query the index.
# You can chain together multiple Criteria by making a comma separated list of hashtables.
# Piping to the Initialize-Item command will convert SearchResultItem to Item.
# PS master:\> help Find-Item -Examples 

Find-Item -Index sitecore_master_index -Criteria @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_templatename"; Value = "Sample Item"} | Initialize-Item
```

**Example:** Get-Item with fast query

```
# This example takes advantage of the fast query. Substitute for your use case.

$query = "fast:/sitecore//*[@@templatename='Sample Item']"
Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query $query
```

The book we've put together may also prove beneficial.
https://www.gitbook.com/book/sitecorepowershell/sitecore-powershell-extensions/details

Comment: the syntax fast:/ does not work any longer within Sitecore 9.02... any idea or workaround? changing the fast query to a slow query, it applies the maximum returned result of 100....

Comment: Try it and let me know if it works for you, since what was working on Sitecore 7.5 stopped working on 9.02 not sure if the issue is with PowerShell or Sitecore itself...